# Firestore Query whereEqualto and Document not getting the data from Firestore DB

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to working with Android studio and Firestore DB.
I am trying to load few lines of a text from firestore into my android app. I noticed while debugging that the line of code whereEqualto field name does not read the desired data. I do not know where I am going wrong while fetching data. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code.

ViewActivity.class

```
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static String topic_name;
    ImageButton next, previous;
    TextView text_area;
    private Information infodb;
    public static List<String> mFragments;
    private Query query;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewtext);

        FetchDetails();
        text_area= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tf_text);
        next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        previous = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        previous.setOnClickListener(this);



    } 

public void FetchDetails(){
        FirestoreUtil.getCollection("Information Text").whereEqualTo("topic_name",topic_name).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                   
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Information ip = document.toObject(Information.class);
                        mFragments=(ip.getFragments());
                        text_area.setText(ip.getFragments().get(0));
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.next:
                text_area.setText(infodb.getFragments().get(1));
                break;


            case R.id.previous:
               text_area.setText(infodb.getFragments().get(2));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Information.class

```
public class Information {

    public List<String> fragments;
    private int topic_id;
    private String topic_name;
    private String game;
    private String link;
    private int level;


public Information() {

}

public Information(String topic_name, List<String> fragments,String game, String link, int level,int topic_id)
{
    this.fragments = fragments;
    this.topic_name= topic_name;
    this.game=game;
    this.topic_id=topic_id;
    this.level = level;
    this.link=link;


}

    public Information(List<String> fragments) {

    this.fragments=fragments;
    }

    public String getTopic_name() {return topic_name;}
    public void setTopic_name(String topic_name) {
        this.topic_name = topic_name;
    }

    public void setFragments(List<String> fragments) {
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }
    public List<String> getFragments() {
        return fragments;
    }

    public String getGame() { return game; }
    public void setGame(String game) { this.game = game; }

    public String getLink() { return link; }
    public void setLink(String link) { this.link = link; }

        public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }
       public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setTopic_id(int topic_id) {this.topic_id=topic_id;}
    public int getTopic_id() {
        return topic_id;
    }

}
```

[here is a screenshot of my data on firestore console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz3yY.png)

Comment: What's the value of `topic_name` inside your reference? Please also edit your question and share the content of your `Information` class.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have just updated it :) thanks for taking the time to reply

Comment: What does `.getCollection("Information Text")` return and what's the value of `topic_name` inside your reference?

Comment: The issue is that the it doesnt enter this collection at all. topic_name is the string object I have created in the same class.

Comment: just edited the whole doc for a clearer picture

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo, no it isnt

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `.get()` operation to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: @AlexMamo I havent. But the real issue here is unless I specify the specific document path from firestore, it doesnt read the data from firestore.

Comment: Then most likely you really should attach that listener.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code you have provided I observed that the variable `private static topic_name` in ViewActivity.class is declared but not initialized anywhere. So the `topic_name` will have a null value by default. This is the reason you are not getting the documents after the `whereEqualTo(“topic_name”,topic_name)` method.

So please initialize the `private static topic_name` variable with a value which is present in the Firestore Collection. You can initialize it as follows -

```
private static String topic_name = “Understanding PTSD”
```

Also you are using the `FirestoreUtil.getCollection()` method to get the collection. However in the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) a Firestore database reference is used to get the collection. The ‘db’ Firestore database reference can be initialized as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize).

So I will suggest you to initialize the Firestore database reference at the ViewActivity.class level like follows -

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

Then use this reference to to get the collection as follows -

```
db.collection("Information Text").whereEqualTo("topic_name",topic_name).get()
```